# Add instances through a List with UITypeEditor

Tags: c#, list, designer, uitypeeditor

I created the Component MyComp and i defined inside it a Property called SlaveComps managed through a UITypeEditor.

```
public class MyComp : Component
{   
    public MyComp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public MyComp(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    [Editor(Global.cSlaveCompsSelectorEditor, typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public List<MyComp> SlaveComps { get; set; }
}

public class SlaveCompsSelectorEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }        
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        MyComp myComp = context.Instance as MyComp;
        if (myComp.SlaveModules==null)
            myComp.SlaveModules = new List<MyComp>();
        MyComp c1 = new MyComp();            
        myComp.Container.Add(c1);
        MyComp c2 = new MyComp();            
        myComp.Container.Add(c2);
        myComp.SlaveComps.Add(c1);
        myComp.SlaveComps.Add(c2);
        return myComp.SlaveModules;
    }
}
```

What i need to do, is to create a collection of MyComp instances and add them to the SlaveComps property.
The problem is that in the .designer.cs file in which the main MyComp is in, the new instances created appears, but the designer can't generate `.Add` command to add the to SlaveComps.
So in the designer file there are: `MyComp c1 = new MyComp(); MyComp c2 = new MyComp();` but the respective instructions: `mainComp.SlaveModules.Add(c1); mainComp.SlaveModules.Add(c2);` still missing. 
Any idea?

[EDIT]
Found solution; use `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` instead of `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx